# Can ant "fork=true" option run tasks in parallel?

Tags: multithreading, ant

Lets say we have the following ant tasks :

```
<java class="MyTask1" fork="true">...</java>    

<java class="MyTask2" fork="true">...</java>
```

I know fork="true" will start the 2 tasks in separate VM, but:
Will ant start the 2 tasks in parallel? Or it will wait for task1 to terminate before starting task2 ?

Comment: Fork will launch another thread, but the ANT parent thread will still execute sequentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ant will start the second task only after the first task completes. If you want to run the tasks in parallel, you can either use the `<parallel>` task or (less usefully) the `spawn="true"` attribute of the `<java>` task.